# Filtering after a group by produces a different outcome than MySQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following table from which I try to extract all `cust_id` who have bought an item for the first time in January.

I found a way with MySQL but I'm working with Hive and it doesn't work

Consider this table:

```
| cust_id | created             | year | month | item |
|---------|---------------------|------|-------|------|
| 100     | 2017-01-01 19:20:00 | 2017 | 01    | ABC  |
| 100     | 2017-01-01 19:20:00 | 2017 | 01    | DEF  | 
| 100     | 2017-01-08 22:45:00 | 2017 | 01    | GHI  |
| 100     | 2017-08-03 08:01:00 | 2017 | 08    | JKL  |
| 100     | 2017-01-01 21:23:00 | 2017 | 01    | MNO  |
| 130     | 2016-12-06 06:42:00 | 2016 | 12    | PQR  |
| 140     | 2017-01-21 15:01:00 | 2017 | 01    | STU  |
| 130     | 2017-01-29 13:20:00 | 2017 | 01    | VWX  |
| 140     | 2017-04-10 09:15:00 | 2017 | 04    | YZZ  |
```

With the following query, it works:

```
SELECT
  cust_id,
  year,
  month,
  MIN(STR_TO_DATE(created, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS min_date
FROM
  t1
GROUP BY
  cust_id
HAVING
  year = '2017'
  AND
  month= '01'
```

And it returns this table:

```
| cust_id | year | month | min_date            |
|---------|------|-------|---------------------|
| 100     | 2017 | 01    | 2017-01-01 19:20:00 |
| 140     | 2017 | 01    | 2017-01-21 15:01:00 |
```

But in Hive, I cannot filter the fields `year` and `month` with HAVING if they have not been grouped by previously. In other words, the previous query fails.

Instead, the following runs but don't produce the expected result:

```
SELECT
  cust_id,
  year,
  month,
  MIN(unix_timestamp(created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS min_date
FROM
  t1
GROUP BY
  cust_id, year, month
HAVING
  year = '2017'
  AND
  month= '01'
```

cust_id 130 shows up even if the first purchase happened in december 2016

```
| cust_id | year | month | min_date            |
|---------|------|-------|---------------------|
| 100     | 2017 | 01    | 2017-01-01 19:20:00 |
| 130     | 2017 | 01    | 2017-01-29 13:20:00 |
| 140     | 2017 | 01    | 2017-01-21 15:01:00 |
```

Here is the fiddle : [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cc982/3)

Thank you

Comment: MySQL contains several logic flaws, one being not enforcing group by rules.  Your year/month returned by your mysql script is basically a random value from the list of possible values there (try adding 2016 to the fiddle and expanding the where to include 2016...it'll group them into the 2017 line).  MySQL will do the wrong thing without returning an error in this case.  Best solution is to swap to postgres sadly.

Comment: @Twelfth fyi as of MySQL 5.7.5 the full group by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by option is enabled by default

Comment: @FuzzyTree - Finally!!!!  Is that community edition?  Heh, I need to research, thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL query doesn't really work, even if it runs.  Never have "bare" columns in the `group by` or `having` or `order by` (of an aggregation query).  *All* non-aggregated columns should be the arguments to an aggregation function.  In your case, `year` and `month` fall into this category.

What you appear to want in either database is something like this:

```
SELECT cust_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING MIN(created) >= '2017-01-01' AND
       MIN(created) < '2017-02-01';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bare"? I'm doing an equal because my column are all string encoded. Is it best practice to treat strings as if it was a date format (>=, < on strings)?